# Connection failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to php & ajax and I run a simple application, it doesn't work and I don't know why. I'm using mamp, windows 8.1.

Here are the php file:

```
 <?php

 $grId = $_GET["groupId"];
 $limit = $_GET["limit"];

 if ($limit <= 0) {
    $limit = 10;
 }

 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "root";
 $dbname = "productsdb";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }

 $sql = "SELECT id, displayName, role, groupId FROM user where groupId = ? limit ?";

 $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bind_param("ii", $grId, $limit);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->bind_result($id, $displayName, $role, $groupId);

 $users = array();

 while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $user = new StdClass();
    $user->id = $id;
    $user->displayName = $displayName;
    $user->role = $role;
    $user->groupId = $groupId;

    array_push($users, $user);
 }

 echo json_encode($users);

 $stmt->close();
 $conn->close();
?>
```

and the html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#students').hide();
  $("#getStudentsButton").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      url: "getStudentsJson.php",
      data: {groupId: 1, limit: 7},
      success: renderTable
    });
  });

  function renderTable(data) {
    var trHTML = '';
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
      trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.id + '</td><td>' + item.displayName + '</td><td>'
          + item.role + '</td> <td> ' + item.groupId + ' </td></tr>';
    });

    $('#students').append(trHTML);
    $('#students').show();
  }

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

The list of students:
<div id="maindiv">
<table id="students" border="1">
<tr>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Role</th>
  <th>GroupId</th>
</tr>

</table>

</div>
<input id="getStudentsButton" type="button" value="Load students"/>

</body>
</html>
```

I write: http://localhost/nameOfFolder/getStudentsJson.php in the browser and I receive the error:

> Connection failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Now I think the error can be that before installing Mamp I also had Mysql.I have made a new database in phpmyadmin named productsdb with the 4 columns.I think that made there is some conflicts regarding the database from phpmyadmin and my database mysql. And the name localhost that I have written in php file is axiously trying to connect to my local mysql, the one that I have before the one installed with mamp.

Any solution to fix these issues?

Comment: Does it work if you change `$servername = "localhost";` to `$servername = "127.0.0.1";`?

Comment: phpmyadmin is just a php script that connects to a mysql database. can you connect to mysql @ localhost with a tool/client like mysql command line, mysql workbench, etc?

Comment: now it works, I didn't do anything, I think I didn't write well in browser..anyway. the operation doens't work. I can not load the users from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error (2003) Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server' (10061) indicates that the network connection has been refused. You should check that there is a MySQL server running, that it has network connections enabled, and that the network port you specified is the one configured on the server.

[Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html)

This could either be the server is not running (not very likely if you can see the related information in PHPMyAdmin) or possible a firewall issue. You indicated you are on windows so I would start by disabling the firewall and testing connectivity then work through the checklist they provide in the MySQL manual.